# Average of date difference of datetime field (timezone) and date field in python django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I want to get the average of date difference of datetime field (timezone) and date field in python django.

This is the code I have is

```
result = object.aggregate(
    average_difference=Avg(
        F('completed_date') - F('assigned_at'),
        output_field=models.DateTimeField()))
result['average_difference']
```

The issue is that `completed_date` is `DateField` with value `2019-08-21` and `assigned_at` is a `DateTimeField` with value `2019-08-22 03:26:40`,
so the output is wrong.

Comment: What result are you getting and why do you think it is wrong?

Comment: Remember: `DateField` gets casted to `DateTimeField` with time 0, so `completed_date` will be `2019-08-21 00:00:00`

Comment: @Ralf the value for `assigned_to` in db is `2019-08-22 03:26:40` so I when doing the above I am getting -1 as difference. Actually both fields are from same date `(2019-08-21)` and as `assigned_at` field is `DateTimeField` it got converted to `2019-08-22` and hence the difference is -1